# iOS - Issues adding kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment to image

Tags: objective-c, ios, metadata, exif

I'm having problems writing a kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment to my image. My code (overall) works, as it writes GPS coordinates without a hassle. However, writing some additional info in the UserComment field is non-working (and I'm not sure why). Code is:

```
CFDictionarySetValue(mutable, kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f,%0.0f,%0.0f",yaw,pitch,roll]);
```

Anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else is wondering how to do this, I've finally figured it out:

```
NSDictionary *etcDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f,%0.0f,%0.0f",yaw,pitch,roll],kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment,
                               nil];
CFDictionarySetValue(mutable, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, etcDict);
```

Strange, but it works just fine!

Comment: I tried your suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468315/how-do-i-record-a-maker-note-or-user-comment-in-exif but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?