# How do I record a maker note or user comment in EXIF?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, exif

I'm building a camera app, and want to record in the EXIF the settings that the user selected. Most settings have standard fields, but one doesn't, so I thought I'll record it in the maker notes field.

I tried

```
let attachments = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(nil, buffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate) as! NSDictionary)

let exif = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: attachments[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] as! NSDictionary)

exif[kCGImagePropertyExifMakerNote] = "Blah blah"

attachments[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] = exif
```

But when I try

```
exiftool photo.JPG | grep -i maker
```

or

```
exiftool photo.JPG | grep -i blah
```

I don't see the note. All other properties I set in EXIF are showing up.

I then tried setting it as a user comment, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425111/297868):

```
let comment = ["My custom setting": "blah"]

exif[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment] = comment
```

This doesn't work either.

Am I setting the format of the maker note wrong? Isn't it a string? What about the user comment?

Or is there some other field in EXIF that I should be using instead of maker notes or user comment?